# pattern for matching a string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a `java.util.regex.Pattern` that would match strings similar to the following:

```
Unexpected ID 'foo_<some_number>': ERR-125:"IDs": invalid id
```

So I thought the pattern should just be like this:

```
Pattern.compile("Unexpected ID 'foo_*': ERR-125:\"IDs\": invalid id");
```

But that didn't work.
Could anyone tell me why it didn't work? What should I have done instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your `Pattern` is that you are using a **0 or more** (greedy) quantifier **on the underscore**.

Try this:

```
String input = "Unexpected ID 'foo_1': ERR-125:\"IDs\": invalid id";
//                                                   | any digit
//                                                   |  | once or more (greedy)
System.out.println(input.matches("Unexpected ID 'foo_\\d+': ERR-125:\"IDs\": invalid id"));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk use is wrong, try with \d.

Sorry, you have already done it... well.